# ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for job: Sqoop i have tried to create a job in sqoop, but the following error occured

Tags: sqoop, bigdata

```
sqoop job --create myjob --import --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost/classicmodels" --username root --password 123 --table customers -m 1 --taget-dir /manoj280217/sqoop
```

Error:

```
17/02/28 08:56:18 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for job:
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --import
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --connect
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: jdbc:mysql://localhost/classicmodels
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --username
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: root
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --password
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: 123
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --table
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: customers
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -m
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: 1
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --taget-dir
17/02/28 08:56:18 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: /manoj280217/sqoop
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Syntax for sqoop job is

```
sqoop-job (generic-args) (job-args) [-- [subtool-name] (subtool-args)]
```

Your command should be

```
sqoop job --create myjob -- import --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost/classicmodels" --username root --password 123 --table customers -m 1 --taget-dir /manoj280217/sqoop
```

*See the space between `--` and `import`*

Answer (score 0):

this sounds weird but this is how you fix the problem: Make sure you manually type the whole command instead of copy/pasting it. ps also " " are not needed for jdbc

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question already has an accepted solution so please refrain from adding new answers unless they add something new.

Answer (score 0):

most of the time issue arises only because of spacing and quotations.This is always the case with me. Retype the command and take care of the same.