# trying to use sqoop job for incremental import, getting the following errors

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

This is the code I'm using to create a sqoop job for incremental import,a file already exists in hdfs with data stored. I added few more rows to check the incremental import on sqoop but I'm getting the error as below, please help, Thanks in advance.

```
sqoop job \
--create incimp \
--import \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://<localhost>;database=<db>" \
--username "username" \
--password "password" \
--driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" \
--table "tablename" \
--append --check-column "columnname" \
--last-value "<name>" \
--incremental lastmodified \
--fields-terminated-by ',' \
--target-dir "<hdfs-path>" \
-m 1

**18/01/10 12:24:39 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for job:
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --import
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --connect
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: jdbc:sqlserver://<localhost>;database=<db>
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --username
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: username
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --password
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: password
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --driver
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --table
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: tablename
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --append
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --check-column
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: columnname
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --last-value
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: <name>
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --incremental
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: lastmodified
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --fields-terminated-by
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: ,
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --target-dir
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: <hdfs-path>
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -m
18/01/10 12:24:39 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: 1
Try --help for usage instructions.**
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for job: Sqoop i have tried to create a job in sqoop, but the following error occured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499718/error-tool-basesqooptool-error-parsing-arguments-for-job-sqoop-i-have-tried-to)

Comment: That helped, Thank you.